# uniqueness of irreducible polynomials in a Galois field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Trying to get through a comprehension sticking point in arithmetic in a Galois field.

$GF(8)$ has the following irreducible polynomials: ([https://people.computing.clemson.edu/~westall/851/rs-code.pdf](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/%7Ewestall/851/rs-code.pdf))

$x{^3}+x+1$ and $x{^3}+x{^2}+1$

In the above reference, $5 \cdot 6$  yields $(x+1)$ remainder $(x+1)$ using the first polynomial.

When I multiply using the second polynomial, I obtain $(1)$ remainder $(x{^2})$

My question is, am I doing the arithmetic wrong, or are arithmetic results in a finite field dependent upon the irreducible polynomial (i.e., a polynomial defines a "unique" field)?

Comment: Can you write the part of $5\cdot 6$ in your post? In $GF(8)$ we have $6=0$ of course.

Comment: Each of the irreducible cubics gives you a field of $8$ elements. They are isomorphic. But the isomorphism  does not carry $x$ to $x$, rather to $x^{-1}$ [which of course can be expressed as a polynomial in $x$].